# storing database values to typescript interface

Tags: typescript, interface, storing-data

i have been assigned a task for quite sometime now and im just wondering if anyone can walk me through how to store values from my database to a typescript interface. basically i have an interface that looks like this:

```
export interface Project {
    projectName: string;
}

export interface DashboardTeam {
    teamName: string;
    projects: DashboardProject[];
}

export interface DashboardData {
    teams: DashboardProject[];
}
```

where projectName and teamName are the fields where i want it taken from my database. How should i go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

> How should i go about doing this

You have a few interface names inconsistent (e.g. there is no usage of `Project`). I believe the interfaces you are looking for are :

```
export interface DashboardProject { // Fixed the name for you
    projectName: string;
}

export interface DashboardTeam {
    teamName: string;
    projects: DashboardProject[];
}

export interface DashboardData {
    teams: DashboardTeam[];   // Fixed the name for you
}
```

Comment: oh right sorry. But given now that i have fixed this, how can i store values th these?

To be more specific, i have an api that gives a stream of data. Now with that stream of data, i want to store it so i can use as a component. but as of now, no values are being stored

Comment: That is highly dependent on your `stream` implementation and the `database` implementation